# Leonardo sketch and bootloader hex file combination

Tags: arduino-leonardo, bootloader

Can I combine Leonardo sketch hex file with the Leonardo bootloader hex file?
I would like to program blank Atmega32U4 with one shot.

Comment: Yes you can, and there are programs available to download that will allow you to combine .HEX files.  Ask google. The magic term is "Intel I8HEX". or "Intel HEX"